# Is there any active alternative available for Google Apps Script available?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

Is there any active alternative available for Google Apps Script available?
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: Really depends on what you're trying to do - this question is way too broad to give a yes/no answer.

Comment: For achieving what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use any of the Google APIs with any of your language of preference's client libraries.

You can find the [official libraries here](https://github.com/googleapis)

Using Apps Script provides a way of making requests to Google APIs without going through the OAuth flow.